# Command to find a folder inside folders

Tags: linux, shell, command

I need a terminal command to find all instances of a folder inside folders.

I need to find all instances folders with the name '**builder**' inside the folder '**www**' including all folders inside 'www'.

I tried with:

```
find www -path '*/builder/*' -type d > list
```

but nothing, no error.

Answer (score 1):

Proper way of using `find`

`find www -name "*builder*" -type d -print`

(or)

`find www -name "*builder*" -type d -printf "%f\n"`

where a glob construct `*builder*` is passed as input to the `-name` field which searches all directories under `www/` whose names have the string present.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
find www -name builder -type d
```

This will print the relative pathes (starting with www) to all folders named "builder" on standard output, one path per line.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an
answer really needs a bit more detail than this.  Please
[edit] to explain how this will solve the problem.
Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.